# Что возвращает include/require?

Tags: php

Содержимое файла **canChangeStatus.php**:

```
<?php

return array (
    1 => [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
    2 => [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],
    3 => [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
    4 => [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],
);
```

Подключаю файл и вывожу `$can`:

```
$can = include_once ROOT.'/config/canChangeStatus.php';
var_dump($can);

// bool(true)
```

Почему тогда работает данная конструкция:

```
var_dump( $can[$userRights][$new-1]) //int(1) или int(0)
```

> UPD Метод:

```
public static function checkCanUserChangeСurrentOnSelected ( int $userRights, int $new ) {

$can = include_once ROOT.'/config/canChangeStatus.php';

echo "Вызов метода checkCanUserChangeСurrentOnSelected <br>";

var_dump($can);

# Разрешено ли пользователю с данными правами поменять текущий статус на выбранный ( 1 = разрешено )
# -1 т.к. отсчёт массива начинается с нуля

if ( $can[$userRights][$new-1] === 0 ) throw new Exception(' К сожалению, вы не можете изменить текущий статус на выбранный! 11');

return true;

}
```

Вызов:

```
# Может ли сотрудник с данными ему правами менять текущий статус на выбранный
            self::checkCanUserChangeСurrentOnSelected ( $userGroup, $authorizations['statusId'] );
```

Вывод:

```
Вызов метода checkCanUserChangeСurrentOnSelected
<br>
bool(true)
```

Версия **PHP 7.2.**

Comment: так не бывает. это какая-то опечатка в коде или ошибка в тестах. вопрос можно удалять

Comment: @Ипатьев ещё как быват)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) ведёт себя так:

> include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful
>   includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1. It is
>   possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in
>   order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script
>   which called it. Also, it's possible to return values from included
>   files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a
>   normal function.

В дополнение к этому у вас используется [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php):

> This is a behavior similar to the include statement, with the only
>   difference being that if the code from a file has already been
>   included, it will not be included again, and include_once returns
>   TRUE.

В вольном переводе картина следующая:

- оба вернут `FALSE` и `WARNING` при ошибке
- `include_once` вернёт `TRUE` если файл уже был подключен ранее. Это полностью объясняет наблюдаемое вами поведение. В текущем виде ваша функция `checkCanUserChangeСurrentOnSelected` может работать максимум один раз.
- вернут значение из `return` выражения, если такое было встречено на уровне файла (как `canChangeStatus.php` в вопросе)
- значение `1` если файл обработан, но `return` выражения не было

Comment: Мелкий тут мелкий там) Это я про forum.php.su) Такого нет русскоязычной версии php.net) Спасибо!

Comment: В русскоязычной версии это тоже описано. Ну а меня ещё в паре мест заметить можно, есть такое.

Comment: А как он мог быть подключён, если я его только в этом методе подключаю?

Comment: значит этот метод вызывался уже где-то ранее

Answer (score -2):

`require` и `include` вернут то, что вернёт скрипт, который они подключают. Но обратите внимание на `_once`. Это другая функция (хотя и очень похожая).

Скорее всего вы уже подключали свой скрипт раньше.

return.php:

```
<?php

return 'Hello';
```

main.php:

```
<?php

$foo = include_once __DIR__ . '/return.php';
var_dump($foo); // 'Hello'

$bar = include_once __DIR__ . '/return.php';
var_dump($bar); // true
```

Для скриптов, которые возвращают значение используйте `require` или `include` без `_once`.

Comment: `Это другая функция ..` это вообще не функции.

Comment: @Lexx918 верно подмечено